# How to use Not Equal with CASE statement in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which is written below. please first have a look on this query.

```
SELECT 
    T3.[AcctName],
    SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget,(Select sum(T3.[Debit]/85) From JDT1 T3 ) as 'CurrentBudget'
FROM 
    OBGT T0
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         CASE 
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments' 
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses' 
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations'
            ELSE 'Alterations/Renovations'
         END as [AcctName],
         [AcctCode]
     FROM 
         OACT AS T1) AS T3 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T3.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN 
    OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
WHERE 
    T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY 
    T3.[AcctName], T2.[Name]
```

In this query you can see the cases. I want another column here, for that, if AcctName does not match any of them which are defined in cases then there should be the another column like 'Other Expenses'.e.g  as you can see all alias like if WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries' and all. i want something if T1.[AcctName] != %Salaries%, %Consultants%,%Expense% and so on then it should be as 'Other Expense'. I don't know how to get that. Please experts help me with this.

Comment: Not getting your question, what is the problem?

Comment: No case statement there, just a case expression...

Comment: Redesign your database, add a table cost_categories which stores all these categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place that one in ELSE condition, it works !!!

```
ELSE 'Other Expenses'
```

Ultimately it shows the same result whether you use `NOT Equal` or `ELSE` with your query.

Still if you are happy to use `NOT EQUAL` inside a case...use this <> Operator.

For More Reference...refer the following link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/0dff067e-7b8d-4b74-b123-978683caee0a/using-a-not-equal-in-sql-case-expression

Answer (score 3):

Or i dont understand you, or just change your `ELSE`:

```
SELECT T3.[AcctName],
       SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget,(Select sum(T3.[Debit]/85) From JDT1 T3 ) as 'CurrentBudget'
FROM OBGT T0
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations'
                ELSE 'Other Expenses'
           END as [AcctName],
           [AcctCode]
    from OACT AS T1
    ) as T3 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T3.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
where T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY T3.[AcctName],T2.[Name]
```

Like this ?

Comment: Please see edits .. i hope now it will be clear to you . @Tiago